# Out of boundary detection in OpenCL

Tags: c++, opencl

I was experimenting with OpenCL (C++ interface) and, without noticing it, I created a buffer for 10 integers using buffer size equal to `10`, instead of `10 * sizeof(int)`, but the code run apparently without issues.

Now, I *believe* that this could be possible because I created the buffer with `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR` flag and this made possible to access out of boundary memory (though I am not sure of this).

So, my question is: is it possible to enforce out of bounds error checking in OpenCL, so that any access outsize a given area is reported?

Comment: I'm not experienced with OpenCL so I cannot tell if this is the case, but it might be useful to know if your code is compiled as release or debug. I know few libraries that use such asserts and/or exceptions only when in debug mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other posters have already indicated, out-of-bound checking is currently not supported by OpenCL drivers. While tools like the WebCL Validator are promising in this area, I would like to mention another path, based on existing tools, which has helped me in the past. By using the [FreeOCL CPU driver](https://code.google.com/p/freeocl/), which relies on a standard C++ compiler to compile your kernels (after a source-to-source translation step) you can use a tool like `valgrind` on your final program and get the typical `valgrind` error messages like this:

```
==5863== Thread 6:
==5863== Invalid write of size 1
==5863==    at 0xD61FA5D: __FCL_kernel_krnl_route_pkt (filehFymmN:27)
```

You can then directly refer to the C++ version of the kernel (`/tmp/filehFymmN` line 27 in the example) to find where the offending operation happened.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try the WebCL Validator: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/webcl-validator

It's a command-line tool that instruments your OpenCL kernel source code with run-time checks for out-of-bounds memory accesses. It's still work in progress, so any feedback would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

Long answer:  ATI and NVIDIA are very forgiving for accessing memory out-of-bounds, but Intel will crash (haven't tested AMD cpus).

For something like an Anisotropic filter where you are accessing n, n + 1, and n - 1, you should either use global offsets to avoid accessing memory out of bounds or check in the kernel with `if` statements.  Global Offset is nice, but NVIDIA doesn't support it, so there is that.

Unfortunately, using try / catch on the host code doesn't seem to work either since there is magic being done in the OpenCL.dll you are linking to.

Note: This is on SDK and code about 4 months old, dunno if it has changed since then.

Comment: As an additional information. This is not a missing feature of ATI/nVIDIA. It is just that the GPUs are limited on these aspect, and taking care of all the memory accesses would be a big problem. So, if the GPU access out-of-bound you will not see it. It will return some sort of error to the OpenCL call. No more information I'm afraid.

Comment: I usually don't get an error from the GPU, just corrupted data.  Even for egregious out-of-bounds stuff.

Comment: Depends on the out-of-bound nature. If you overlap a zone, then you will get corrupted data. If you access some protected zone of the GPU, then the kernel will "silently" fail, or crash your computer. In the case it silently fail, the error code will apear only in the kernel event or in the clEnqueueBufferRead() call (CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES), of course, giving corrupted data. At least this is valid for the nVIDIA case.